# How can I extract p-values for individual groups in a linear mixed model using R lmer from lme4 package?

Tags: r, lme4, p-value

I have generated a linear mixed model without problem (naming it modelTemp) in the code by running the lmer function from the lme4 package.

Here's the use of summary() function without issue:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPzoA.png)

However, that only provided the gradient and p value for all the groups/subjects combined together. To find the gradient for each individual group/subject, I used `coef()`, again without problem

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOJtd.png)

Now the question is, can I extract all the p-values for the group/subjects 1 through 8? Does this functionality exist?

Everybody's talking about coefficients for all the groups, and p value for all the groups.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the summary and coef output in a textual format rather than as screenshots?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is not a computational limitation of the package, it's a fundamental limitation of the statistical methodology. One way to look at it is that it's the price you pay for being able to fit coefficients for as many groups as you want while estimating a single top-level parameter (the among-group variance).

If you need more explanation, please ask on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). (There might be a question on this topic there already, but I couldn't find it in a quick search.)

You can extract a kind of uncertainty measure (*conditional standard deviations*) for the deviations of each group from the mean - e.g. via `broom.mixed::tidy(fitted_models, effects = "ran_vals")`, but these can't be converted to p-values.